# Do some Devil Fruits allow the user to swim in water?

Tags: one-piece

If someone had for example a "wood" devil fruit, his body would be entirely made out of wood. Would it be possible then to swim on the water, because naturally wood "swims" or at least floats in the water?

Or does the sea eliminate his wood power and give him his normal body back, so he would drown?

Comment: Will smoke (Smoker DF power) drown? all DF user lose whatever their power if they're thrown at the sea

Comment: @HachikujiMayoi yeah, but smoker can naturally change between smoke and normal body, what if he would be like luffy and can't change his body.

Comment: @HachikujiMayoi They indeed lose their power, but some paramecia keep their body element though, similar to how luffy is still rubber even after jumping into the ocean.

Comment: added water in title to be specific because there is devil fruit that allow you to swim, if that is not what you want to ask then you can rollback.

Answer (score 6):

**No, there are no Devil Fruits that allow a user to swim in water. Every Devil Fruit user has the same basic weakness.**

Since wood is lighter than water, he might be able to float on the water though. While floating on the water, you are submerged for over 50%, which would result in energy drainage for fruit users and make the user unable to move and even if he could master some energy to move his arms or legs, if he wants to move through the water he has to put them in the water, submerging himself more and losing even more energy. So **my guess would be that the user would not drown and be able to motionlessly float around the ocean**. He has to go into the water laying face up though or he would not be able to breath and still drown anyway (but not sink). So I guess if such a user falls into the water and would emerge with his head first fast enough before passing out, he might be able to survive, but probably not for long.

Comment: yeah i had the same thoughts, thx for your confirmation

Comment: I would like to add that there is most deffinantly a devil fruit that allows you to swim. 

Senor Pink has the Sui Sui no Mi, it just doesnt allow him to swim in water.

http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sui_Sui_no_Mi

Comment: @ChenOrihara Well yes, that's true, I'll add "water" to my answer.